# Gradle warning Cannot assign 'LinkedHashMap<String, Object>' to 'Class<xxx>' on IDEA

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

When I use this way to add a property:

```
ext {
    some = [
        ...
    ]
}
```

IDEA shows me a yellow warning on `some`:

```
Cannot assign 'LinkedHashMap<String, Object>' to 'Class<some>'
```

If I make `some` as `String`:

```
ext["some"] = [...]
```

Then the yellow warning disappeared.

Why and what is the right way to add a property on gradle ext?
[image]

Comment: I use it like            ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'      ext.lifecycle_version = '2.2.0'         but i'm not sure about arrays

Comment: Which Gradle DSL are you using, the Groovy-based `build.gradle` or the Kotlin-based `build.gradle.kts`?

Comment: @joschi xxx.gradle, called by build.gradle. gradle version: 6.6.1

Comment: As this syntax should be working fine, can you share more information? 1. Content inside some  
2.  Where is this ext being created?

Comment: @KyzerSoze yes it works fine. But IDEA shows that yellow warning. More info is: `some` is a common map in `a.gradle`, and `apply from: a.gradle` in `build.gradle`. Nothing special, they work fine, but I hate that yellow warning.

Comment: @KyzerSoze I added a picture

Comment: There's only so much IntelliJ can do with Groovy build scripts, I think you'll just need to ignore the colour

Comment: @tim_yates Why IntelliJ tips this?

Comment: Groovy is a hugely dynamic language...  Intellij tries its best, but occasionally gets it wrong :-(

Comment: There is a related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-227629